# ESP32 STA-wifi not starting in mixed mode

Tags: rust, esp32

WiFi starts for the AP but hangs when waiting for STA to start. I don't need the client to connect to any WiFi (only for it to be able to scan nearby APs). However defining a valid AP to connect to doesn't work either. Calling `wifi.connect()` also hangs.

```rust
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // ...
    let sys_loop = EspSystemEventLoop::take()?;
    let nvs = EspDefaultNvsPartition::take()?;
    let peripherals = Peripherals::take()?;

    let mut wifi = BlockingWifi::wrap(
        EspWifi::new(peripherals.modem, sys_loop.clone(), Some(nvs))?,
        sys_loop,
    )?;

    // Start WiFi AP
    start_wifi(&mut wifi)?;
    // ....
}

fn start_wifi(wifi: &mut BlockingWifi<EspWifi<'static>>) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let wifi_configuration = wifi::Configuration::Mixed(
        ClientConfiguration::default(),
        AccessPointConfiguration {
            ssid: SSID.try_into().unwrap(),
            auth_method: AuthMethod::WPA2Personal,
            password: PASSWORD.try_into().unwrap(),
            ..Default::default()
        },
    );

    wifi.set_configuration(&wifi_configuration)?;
    log::info!(target: TAG, "Set Wi-Fi configuration");

    wifi.start()?;
    log::info!(target: TAG, "Started Wi-Fi");

    wifi.ip_wait_while(
        || wifi.wifi().ap_netif().is_up().map(|up| !up),
        Some(Duration::from_secs(45)),
    )?; // Custom version of wifi.wait_netif_up() for debugging
    log::info!(target: TAG, "Wi-Fi ap netif up");

    wifi.ip_wait_while(
        || wifi.wifi().sta_netif().is_up().map(|up| !up),
        Some(Duration::from_secs(180)), // Longer timeout did nothing
    )?;
    log::info!(target: TAG, "Wi-Fi sta netif up");
    // ....
}
```

How can I init STA+AP wifi without connecting to any wifi?

Edit: The station doesn't seem to be able to start no matter the configuration. Alone, mixed, with a valid AP to connect or just calling `default()`

Comment: I think you should modify the WiFi config to ONLY set up the AP mode... while your function inits both AP and STA simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to init both of them other than configuring both. Running `wifi.scan()` with only AP configured causes an error.

Comment: BTW, to answer your last question, it would be `let mut wifi = Esp8266::new();` and then init WiFi in STA+AP mode `wifi.init_sta_ap("YourSSID", "YourPassword", "AP_SSID", "AP_Password").unwrap();`

Comment: I am building with std support and for esp32... There is no function `init_sta_ap` in `EspWifi`.

Comment: I remember it was in header file `user_interface.h`. and the link was:  https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp8266-rtos-sdk/en/latest/api-reference/network/esp_wifi.html#init-sta-ap

Comment: 1st: link is broken, 2nd: still programming on esp32... 3rd; still programming using `esp-rs`